# Class links wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

Im trying to add a tag to a group so when I want to add a group I can add an associated tag to it. What im trying to do is be able to return a list of groups filtered by tags.

```
    List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();
    List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
    public void AddTagtoGroup(Group group, Tag tag)
    {
        group.GroupName(tag.Add);
        return Groups with tags or tags with groups 
    }
```

This is the data contract for groups and tags:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Group")]
public class Group
{

    public Group() // not sure if this has to have a datamember
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "GroupName")]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; } // datamember or not?

}
[DataContract(Name = "Tag")]
public class Tag
{
    [DataMember(Name = "TagName")]
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you want to have the `Tags` property included in your WCF message that gets sent across the wire, then **yes**, it has to be marked with a `[DataMember]` attribute. If you do decorate your classes with `[DataMember]` attributes, then **only what is marked with `[DataMember]`** will be serialized into the WCF message.

Comment: How come a group.GroupName(tag.Add) can add a tag. o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just a bit confused by the code: `group.GroupName(tag.Add)`. Are you trying to reset the group name of your group? And what does the tag.Add method do? I would have thought you might like an Add method in your group to add a tag to your current `List<Tag> Tags` list, like this:

```
group.Add(tag)
```

instead. Or, if you need to find the right group first in your `Groups` list you might prefer just to pass in the GroupName and do a search for it, so you'll get:

```
public void AddTagtoGroup(string groupName, Tag tag)
{
    Group group = FindGroupByName(groupName);
    if (group != null) {
        group.Add(tag);
    }
}
```

In `FindGroupByName` you'll go through your `Groups` list and check each one's name against the one supplied. Or you could use a HashSet of Groups or a Dictionary to speed up that part. Then just make a getter for your `Groups`.

In reply to your questions:

- You will only need to mark the `Group()` constructor as a `DataMember` if it needs to be called client-side
- Yes, the list of Tags will need to be marked as `DataMember` as, I think, from your code it will be needed client-side

You might need to be a bit more specific, is this Adding a `Tag` to a `Group` client-side? To make that clearer, you'd be using `GroupProxy` and `TagProxy` where appropriate. Use these in your code and they are the ones that talk to the WCF Service. Then it should be obvious what members/methods they need to call and mark each one of those in the Contract/Service (you might also want to consider separating your Contract out to an interface and then keep the actual implementation in a class (which will become the Service) that implements that interface.